# Remote access SSH problem

Tags: ssh, networking, fedora, ftp, irix

I have been asked to setup a lab with 1 PC (fedora 18 OS) and 4 SGI (IRIX 6.5 OLD OS).
I am using a switch to connect them to university's network, and I asked tech guys to assign static IPs to them. Now I have statics assigned and I can ping all the machines, but I can't use SSH or FTP for a remote access. Do I need to make any configuration?

Comment: Are your static IPs in the same netblock?  Could be a firewall between them.

Answer (score 2):

You trivially have to start the services (see `netstat -alnp`). And you have to see that these services are not blocked by a firewall (see `iptables -L -nv`).

Comment: Note that that covers services and the _local_ firewall on the Linux machine, the Irixes are probably different. Also, there might be a firewall in front of the lab. First check if you can ssh in inside the lab, then call tech people if it doesn't work from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install or check if ssh and ftp server is running on each box and it is not getting blocked by any firewall rules.

/etc/init.d/vsftpd status
and
/etc/init.d/ssh status

temporarily disable firewall , if it is running. 
/etc/init.d/iptables stop

Comment: Can you provide the details on how someone would do this? Answers should be able to provide specifics with respect to the original question, see the faq: http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq